# How to create Gson object for entity class which has timestamp value?

Tags: java, json

I have a payload string and want to change it to values of entity. The payload as below:

```
{"resultCode":"200","resultMessage":"Success","consent":[{"name":"A","sourceSystem":"IGN","updateBy":"Admin","remark":"good","version":"1.0","updateDate":1600658621871},{"name":"B","sourceSystem":"IGN","updateBy":"Admin","remark":"good","version":"2.0","updateDate":1874819158457},{"name":"C","sourceSystem":"IGN","updateBy":"Admin","remark":"good","version":"3.0","updateDate":1358819159457}]}
```

And the entities:

```
public class ListConsentResponse {

    private String resultCode;
    private String resultMessage;
    private List<ConsentDTO> consent;
    public String getResultCode() {
        return resultCode;
    }
    public void setResultCode(String resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }
    public String getResultMessage() {
        return resultMessage;
    }
    public void setResultMessage(String resultMessage) {
        this.resultMessage = resultMessage;
    }
    public List<ConsentDTO> getConsent() {
        return consent;
    }
    public void setConsent(List<ConsentDTO> consent) {
        this.consent = consent;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class ConsentDTO {

    private String name;
    private String sourceSystem;
    private String updateBy;
    private String remark;
    private String version;
    private Timestamp updateDate;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSourceSystem() {
        return sourceSystem;
    }
    public void setSourceSystem(String sourceSystem) {
        this.sourceSystem = sourceSystem;
    }
    public String getUpdateBy() {
        return updateBy;
    }
    public void setUpdateBy(String updateBy) {
        this.updateBy = updateBy;
    }
    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }
    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public Timestamp getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }
    public void setUpdateDate(Timestamp updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }
}
```

But when I parse to json using GsonBuilder :

```
ListConsentResponse listConsentResponse = Utility.createGsonObject()
                    .fromJson(payload, ListConsentResponse.class);
```

I have error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1600658621871
```

Is there any way help me get parse the string with Timestamp value to entity. Or at least can I change the Timestamp value to String value in payload (For example change 1600658621871 to "1600658621871").
Thanks.

Comment: You should probably use a `long` for the `updateBy` field. Then, later convert it to your `Timestamp` class manually.

Comment: Yes I also think so. But I get the payload from other source, that it only supply the payload and I cannot change the value before.

Comment: I understand that. That's why I asked you to change your POJO only.

Comment: I made a typo in the first comment, I mean the `updateDate` field.

Comment: Yes thanks @KartikOhri, it seem run for my case.